# Android List Layout

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement a "listview" style interface on Android, the layout should be like the image, that is each "row" of data in the list may have multiple subrows (?)

Any suggestions on any standard controls that I could use for this?

[image: HTML based layout to be replicated]

Comment: Are you asking about the technical implementation or the best kind of user experience?  If you're looking for open-source code to re-use or something like that you'll want a different forum.

Comment: That forum being www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

From a UX perspective, it looks like the table you've got is a bit dense for a smartphone screen.  I would start by figuring out which of these columns people are going to want to browse by.  Are they scanning for a particular concept ID, or are they going to want a list sorted by type, or are they reading all the descriptions?  If you answer those questions you should end up with two pieces of information:

- Which data is the most important
- Whether your users will be [browsing or searching](http://www.uie.com/articles/browse_vs_search/)

If browsing, you want to make it so your data is indexed by that "important data" you think they'll want to find things by.  Make it a big, scrolling list that gives real-time feedback about how far through the list the user is.  Let them quick-move to a section and then precision-browse from there with similar gestures.  When they find what they are looking for, let them highlight it or open it for more information.

If searching, return a list that shows the data on which they searched as well as some more detailed information lined up next to it (for instance, the display name).  Again, they might be able to highlight or select an entry to see all its information.

You might be able to save yourself a column's worth of information by color-coding entries by type, if there are only a few, or by returning search results in categories by type.

Hope some of that helps or inspires.